# Estructura with con select y funcion dentro de un cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

es posible usar la estructura with con una funcion dentro de un cursor, no se si lo estoy declarando de manera inadecuada, me esta saliendo el siguiente error `using with function inside procedure pl sql statement is not supported`

```
CURSOR c_detail IS
WITH 
FUNCTION CALC_NUMBER(FOB_ITEM    NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
                     FOB_TOTAL   NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
                     WEIGHT NUMBER DEFAULT 0) RETURN NUMBER
     IS
     PESO_BRUTO_ITEM NUMBER :=0;
     BEGIN
         IF( (FOB_ITEM > 0) AND (FOB_TOTAL > 0 AND WEIGHT> 0 )) THEN
             PESO_BRUTO_ITEM := (FOB_ITEM * WEIGHT) / FOB_TOTAL;
         END IF;
         RETURN PESO_BRUTO_ITEM;
END CALC_NUMBER;  
test_data AS
(
SELECT 36.25 AS FOB_I, 12536.36 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 15.36 AS FOB_I, 3678.65 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 878.77 AS FOB_I, 89653.13 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual
)
SELECT TD.FOB_I,
       TD.FOB_TOTAL,
       CALC_NUMBER(TD.FOB_I, TD.FOB_TOTAL, TD.W) WEIGHT
  FROM test_data TD
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ejecutar una función dentro de un cursor declarado en un bloque anónimo, debes crear la función como un objeto independiente en un esquema accesible, de forma similar como lo realizo en el siguiente ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumar
( a NUMBER
, b NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN a + b;
END sumar;
/
--
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_numeros IS
        WITH foo_data AS (
            SELECT 1 a, 2 b FROM dual UNION
            SELECT 3 a, 4 b FROM dual UNION
            SELECT 5 a, 6 b FROM dual
        )
        SELECT a, b, sumar(a, b) c FROM foo_data;
BEGIN
    FOR r_numeros IN c_numeros LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('La suma de '||r_numeros.a||' y '||r_numeros.b||' es '||r_numeros.c);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```